# Laravel Paypal POST request is rejected

Tags: php, laravel, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to implement IPN in my Laravel project, a post request from my website is working thanks to "csrf",

i try to implement it like written here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/ht-ipn/

in my routes/web.php:

```
Route::post('i', [IController::class, 'y'])->name('i');
```

and in IController whats written on the side:

```
public function y()
    {
        error_log('function y called');
        // STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.

// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');............
```

The error_log doesn't show up, means the function is never entered.

**Question: How can i force Laravel to except POSTS From Paypal?**

Answer (score 3):

You can Exclude URIs From CSRF Protection in laravel.

Goto `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`  and add url which you want to exclude csrf token.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'i',
       
    ];
}
```

As document says

> Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection.
> For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are
> utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe
> webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know
> what CSRF token to send to your routes.
>
> Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web
> middleware group that the App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider applies
> to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also
> exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the
> VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: YES! Thanx. and i can't upvote :-( StOv why?

Comment: @Strella . you can only accept answer now because for voting you need at least 15 reputations point   https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Now I know, another ingenius move is that you can't comment below 50 and have to submit an answer.